# Cannot send more than a few SendGrid emails with Node.js & Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I am working on an app using Node.js as a backend on Firebase Functions and SendGrid to send mass emails to customers at one time when the tracking for a bulk of orders is ready. I can upload a CSV to the system with a list of 1-3, maybe a few more and will all work properly, but when I have as many as 100 or 1000, the system will not send and I get the error:

`Error with sending tracking emails: Error: socket hang up` followed by `Error setting processed to true: Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded` on Firebase Function's Node.js server logs. Is there a maximum for sending emails in bulk like this? Any clues on where the issue may lie?

**Relevant Code Snippet:**

```
"use strict";
import functions = require('firebase-functions');
import * as uuid from 'uuid';
import admin = require("firebase-admin");
import { DocumentSnapshot } from '@google-cloud/firestore';
import { RESPONSE_TYPES } from './common';

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const request = require("request");
const Papa = require('papaparse');

const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
sgMail.setApiKey(functions.config().sendgrid_api.key)
    

export const onUploadCreated = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}/uploads/{uploadId}')
    .onCreate(async (snap: DocumentSnapshot, context: functions.EventContext) => {
        const newValue = snap.data();
        if (newValue === null || newValue === undefined) {
            return;
        }
        
        try {
            const allPromises: Array<Promise<any>> = [];
            console.log("Upload type set to set shipment tracking info...")
            const orders: any = [];

            // Parse through uploaded CSV
            const options = {
                download: true,
                header: true,
                worker: true
            };

            const parseStream = await Papa.parse(Papa.NODE_STREAM_INPUT, options);
            allPromises.push(parseStream);

            const dataStream = await request.get(newValue.fileUrl).pipe(parseStream);
            allPromises.push(dataStream);
            
            let parseError = "";
            allPromises.push(
                await parseStream.on("data", async (chunk: any) => {
                    if(
                        chunk['Order ID'] && chunk['Order ID'] !== undefined && chunk['Order ID'] !== null &&
                        chunk['Order Number'] && chunk['Order Number'] !== undefined && chunk['Order Number'] !== null &&
                        chunk['First Name'] && chunk['First Name'] !== undefined && chunk['First Name'] !== null && 
                        chunk['Last Name'] && chunk['Last Name'] !== undefined && chunk['Last Name'] !== null && 
                        chunk['Email'] && chunk['Email'] !== undefined && chunk['Email'] !== null && 
                        chunk['Tracking'] && chunk['Tracking'] !== undefined && chunk['Tracking'] !== null
                    ){ 
                        // If in e notation, throw error
                        if(/e\+|E\+/g.test(chunk['Tracking'])){
                            parseError = "Tracking is in E notation, please reformat as outlined in NOTE 3 and re-upload."
                        } else {
                            await orders.push({
                                id: chunk['Order ID'],
                                number: chunk['Order Number'],
                                productName: chunk['Product Name'] || '',
                                productSize: chunk['Product Size'] || '',
                                productVariant: chunk['Product Variant'] || '',
                                firstName: chunk['First Name'],
                                lastName: chunk['Last Name'],
                                email: chunk['Email'],
                                tracking: chunk['Tracking'],
                                carrier: chunk['Carrier'] || '',
                                method: chunk['Method'] || '',
                            })
                        }
                    } else {
                        parseError = "Required columns were not properly defined properly. Please check your file follows the NOTES and re-upload."
                    }
                })
            );

            // TODO: if multiple products, we need to just create more rows for each product like BS does
            allPromises.push(
                await dataStream.on("finish", async () => {
                    if(orders.length > 1000){
                        parseError = "You uploaded over 1000 orders to this upload. Please retry by only submitting 1000 orders at a time so we don't overwhelm the servers!"
                    }
                    if(parseError.length === 0){
                        console.log("Parsing complete, no errors. Number of orders processed: " + orders.length + ". Starting to add orders to Firestore Order docs now... ")
                        const emailMessages: { to: any; from: string; subject: string; text: string; html: string; }[] = [];

                        let shopData: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData | any = null;
                        await admin.firestore().collection('public').doc("shop").get().then((shopDoc) => {
                            if (shopDoc.exists) {
                                let docWithMore = Object.assign({}, shopDoc.data());
                                docWithMore.id = shopDoc.id;
                                shopData = docWithMore;
                            } else {
                                console.error("Shop doc doesn't exist!")
                            }
                        }).catch((error) => {
                            console.log("Error getting shop document:", error);
                        })  
                        
                        const batchArray: any = [];
                        batchArray.push(admin.firestore().batch());
                        console.log("batchArray.length: " + batchArray.length);
                        let operationCounter = 0;
                        let batchIndex = 0;
                        let ordersProcessed = 0;
                        allPromises.push(
                            await orders.forEach((order: any) => {
                                const orderRef = admin.firestore().collection('orders').doc(order.id)
                                batchArray[batchIndex].set(
                                    orderRef, 
                                    {
                                        shipment: {
                                            tracking: order.tracking,
                                            carrier: order.carrier || '',
                                            method: order.method || ''
                                        }
                                    }, 
                                    { merge: true }
                                );
                                
                                const htmlEmail = 
                                `
                                <div style="width: 100%; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
                                    ${shopData?.nav?.showLogo ? 
                                        ` 
                                        <div style="text-align: center;">
                                                <img 
                                                    alt="company logo"
                                                    src="${shopData?.logoUrl}"
                                                    width="${shopData?.nav?.logoSize || "200"}" height="auto"
                                                />
                                        </div>
                                        `
                                        : "" 
                                    }
                                    ${shopData?.nav?.showTitle ? `<h1 style="margin: 20px 0 0 0; text-align: center;">${shopData?.name}</h1>` : ""}
                                    
                                    <div style="margin: auto; width: 70%; padding: 1%;">
                                        <h2>Great news ${order.firstName}!</h2>
                                        <p>
                                            Your order #${order.number} has shipped with the tracking # <b>${order.tracking}</b>.
                                        </p>
                                        ${order?.productName ? `<p><b>Product Name:</b> ${order.productName}</p>` : ""}
                                        ${order?.productSize ? `<p><b>Product Size:</b> ${order.productSize}</p>` : ""}
                                        ${order?.productVariant ? `<p><b>Product Variant:</b> ${order.productVariant}</p>` : ""}
                                        ${order?.method ? `<p><b>Shipping Method:</b> ${order.method}</p>` : ""}
                                        ${order?.carrier ? `<p><b>Shipping Carrier:</b> ${order.carrier}</p>` : ""}
                                        ${shopData?.emails?.order?.shipment ?? ''}
                                        <p>
                                            Feel free to reach out to <a href="mailto:${shopData?.emails?.support ?? `help@email.com`}">${shopData?.emails?.support ?? `help@email.com`}</a> if you have any questions!
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                `
                                const msg = {
                                    to: order.email,
                                    from: `noreply@email.com`,
                                    subject: `${shopData?.name} Order #${order.number} Shipped!`,
                                    text: `
                                        Great news! We shipped out your order with the tracking #${order.tracking}! 
                                        ${order?.method ? ` Shipping Method: ${order.method} ` : ""}
                                        ${order?.carrier ? ` Shipping Carrier: ${order.carrier} ` : ""}
                                    `,
                                    html: htmlEmail,
                                }


                                emailMessages.push(msg)

                                operationCounter++;
                                ordersProcessed++;
                                if (operationCounter === 499) {
                                    console.log("operationCounter: " + operationCounter)
                                    batchArray.push(admin.firestore().batch());
                                    batchIndex++;
                                    operationCounter = 0;
                                }
                            })
                        );
                        
                        // Attempt to send out emails, if it fails, do not continue with adding changes to Firestore! Sending email is the main purpose of this process.
                        allPromises.push(
                            sgMail.send(emailMessages).then(async () => {
                                console.log(`${emailMessages.length} tracking emails sent successfully!`);
                                console.log("Starting to push batchArray.length: " + batchArray.length);
                                let batchesProcessed = 0;
                                allPromises.push(
                                    await batchArray.forEach(async (batch: any) => {
                                        console.log("batchesProcessed: " + batchesProcessed);
                                        batchesProcessed++;
                                        allPromises.push(await batch.commit())
                                        if(batchesProcessed === batchArray.length){
                                            console.log("Done pushing " + batchesProcessed + " batches!");
                                            allPromises.push(
                                                admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(context.params.userId).collection('uploads').doc(context.params.uploadId).set({ 
                                                    processed: true,
                                                    response: {
                                                        type: RESPONSE_TYPES.SUCCESS,
                                                        message: `Successfully sent ${emailMessages.length} tracking emails and updated ${ordersProcessed} orders on the database with this tracking info.`,
                                                        read: false,
                                                        timestamp: Date.now()
                                                    }
                                                }, { merge: true }).then(() => {
                                                    console.log("Set upload processed to true.")
                                                })
                                            );
                                        }
                                    })
                                );
                            }).catch((error: any) => {
                                console.log("Error with sending tracking emails: " + error);
                                allPromises.push(
                                    admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(context.params.userId).collection('uploads').doc(context.params.uploadId).set({ 
                                        processed: true,
                                        response: {
                                            type: RESPONSE_TYPES.ERROR,
                                            message: `Error sending tracking emails: ${error}`,
                                            read: false,
                                            timestamp: Date.now()
                                        }
                                    }, { merge: true }).then(() => {
                                        console.log("Set upload processed to true.")
                                    }).catch(err => {
                                        console.error("Error setting processed to true: " + err)
                                    })
                                );
                            })
                        )

                        
                    } else {
                        console.error("Error parsing shipments CSV: " + parseError)
                        allPromises.push(
                            admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(context.params.userId).collection('uploads').doc(context.params.uploadId).set({ 
                                processed: true,
                                response: {
                                    type: RESPONSE_TYPES.ERROR,
                                    message: `Error parsing shipments CSV: ${parseError}`,
                                    read: false,
                                    timestamp: Date.now()
                                }
                            }, { merge: true }).then(() => {
                                console.log("Set upload processed to true and parseError")
                            }).catch(error => {
                                console.error("Error setting processed to true and parseError: " + error)
                            })
                        );
                    }
                })
            );

            return Promise.all(allPromises)
        } catch(error) {
            console.error("Error: " + error);
            return;
        }
});
```

Comment: did you solved this? having the same issue

Comment: @ulises.olave I have not :/ Haven't gone back and taken a look at the fix but I likely will soon here, ad I will update this post!

Comment: I solved the issue, in my case I wasn't handling correctly the promise, I just needed to put "return" before the .send() method. Now I can send up to 1000 mails per api call

Answer (score 1):

The error you get has nothing to do with Firebase. This is a SendGrid limit for Free Accounts, as you can see on [this page](https://sendgrid.com/pricing/).

The limit is 100 emails per day. To send more emails you'll need to upgrade your account to a paid one.

Comment: Hi, I am currently paying for Essentials 100K || 100,000 emails/month || $0.00075 per additional email || $29.95/month , so not on a free plan!